# clear textarea field after hitting submit?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a textarea that users can paste/type a block of text into.
However, I want the input text to disappear once the user clicks submit.

I'm having problems doing this as I think I end up clearing the input text before it has had a chance to submit?

Comment: Hi, I help you to add the codes to the SO code snippets. Please fix some bugs of the codes.

Comment: Hi thank you! I accidentally pasted the wrong code for the html sorry! is it working now?

Comment: should be working now, sorry I'm very new to stackoverflow!

Comment: No worries, it is better to show an executable example and people can figure out your problem easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the input element and set its value to an empty string.

Add this line in after appending the input value.

```
document.getElementById("input").value = '';
```

```js
// enter or paste a block of text, once button SUBMIT TEXT is clicked, words can be selected  to black out.//
let btn = document.getElementById("btn");
let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let inputValue = document.getElementById("input").value;

  // loops through each word that has been typed/pasted into TEXTAREA//
  inputValue.split(" ").forEach(word => {
    const element = document.createElement("span");

    //and then creates a span for each individual word so that each one can be clickable//
    element.innerHTML = word;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    document.getElementById("myPoetry").appendChild(element);
    
    document.getElementById("input").value = '';

    //once a user clicks on a span, the background colour will change to black
    //(.highlighted in css), thus creating the blackout poetry tool
    //if a user clicks on the word again, it will 'deselect' it, turning it back to a
    //white background
    element.onclick = () => {
      element.classList.toggle("highlighted");
    };
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">            
            <textarea id='input' placeholder="Copy & paste a block of text you'd like to create poetry from!" ></textarea> 
            <div class="myPoetry" id ="myPoetry"></div>
        </div>
                      
        <div class= "button">
            <button id="btn">Submit Text</button>
            <button id="download">Save</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: My Pleasure  Happy Coding!